# c++-Most efficient way of processing big file records in to a cpp container

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a 2GB sized file with over 4 millions of records, each in one row. Now I need to process the record one by one and throw the result of each record into a container, say `vector<string>`.

I am planning on building a multi-threaded program to finish the task working like this:

1. Read the whole file into a `vector<string>`, called `all_origin_records` in a single thread. Each row of record as an element of the `all_origin_records`.
2. Create N threads. Each thread takes charge of the i-th portion of the `all_origin_records` and puts the results into its own `vector<string> results`
3. Aggregate `vector<string> results`s of all threads in a single thread into `vector<string> all_results`, which involves **moving** container elements.

Only the 2nd step is multi-threaded, so I wonder can I parallelize the 1st and 3rd steps? Especially the 3rd step. Or is there any better solution?

I am considering that each thread writes result record directly to the `all_results`. But that could introduce lock-contention among N threads. And it seems the same as using BlockQueue.

Comment: Do you need to do this more than once diring your program run, (AKA is there any point in using a thread pool)?  Are the records fixed-size after processing, (AKA bulk moving is a design fail). 'Read the whole file' can the processing of the first block start after reading 'whole file/N' records - why wait until the whole file is read?

Comment: Why do you even have step 3? Can't you just write the results of each thread to the right place directly?

Comment: And step 1 is probably constrained by the disk rather than CPU unless there's some somewhat expensive parsing going on; multithreading would not fix that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen no, but it allows the possibility of starting the processing much earlier.

Comment: @MartinJames That's a good point.

Comment: *"But that could introduce lock-contention among N threads."* Note that several threads can write to the same vector as long as they don't access the same elements without synchronization. (Except for `std::vector<bool>`.)

Comment: @MartinJames no and yes.

Comment: Even if the record size varies, can the next stage of operations be modified to accept a vector of vectors, so avoiding the moving?

Comment: @BaummitAugen is that also true for vector push?

Comment: @EricZheng No, but can't you just set the right size beforehand? Default-constructing strings is cheap.

Comment: @EricZheng 'no and yes' you're off to the races, then:)  Pre-size the outout vector and have the threads load the processed records right in there, as suggested by Baum earlier.  No move is a good move:)

Comment: @MartinJames true. That could be good tradeoff too

Comment: @BaummitAugen in fact the number of records could vary. I can’t tell how many of them before reading the whole file.

Comment: @EricZheng guess from the file size, or process the whole in blocks, queued to a pool of threads.  You could queue a stuct/class that has the input vector, output vector, write-position, (and error-message string in case of.. issues while the threads are processing:).

Comment: I'm not sure it's so easy to put 2GB of data into one vector. That container would need 2GB of continuous memory to be available. Unless you have a lot of RAM, that might pose a problem.

Comment: @JHBonarius well I haven’t use a distributed computing framework yet since my server seams ok with 2gb memory for now. And by the way, by continuous memory, you mean virtual memory space? I think it is ok for a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest the following:

- start with a simple single-threaded implementation
- run a profiler and measure where you need performance:

  - if its the processing part: go on and distribute the work to a thread-pool
  - if its parsing while reading the data, consider to store/load as binary

you could very well end up with a single-threaded implementation being faster than a multi-threaded one. even if not, you have a nice baseline for performance comparisons to see how much you gained by parallelizing.